# Trying to assign multiple variable to blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I m trying to assign multiple variable to the blade template but it returns an exception

Undefined variable: transactions (View: /home/u305199682/public_html/dash/protected/app/views/pages/template/home.blade.php)

```
$this->layout->nest('content',$page)
    ->with(array(
        'menus' => $this->menus,
        'transactions' => $transaction
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna pass data to a nested view, try

```
$this->layout->nest('content', $page, array(
    'menus' => $this->menus,
    'transactions' => $transaction
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call with for each variable

```
$this
    ->layout
    ->nest('content',$page)
    ->with('menus',$this->menus)
    ->with("transactions",$transaction);
```

or put both variables into 1 array.

```
$passVar = array(
                 'menus' => $this->menus,
                 'transaction' => $transaction
                );

$this
    ->layout
    ->nest('content',$page, $passVar);
```

Comment: `->with()` also takes arrays, not only `(string, array)`.